# Quick question about separating the return values of this function

Tags: python, function

```
## velocity
    def get_velocity(self):
        return ( (self.dx, self.dy) )
    def set_velocity (self, new_velocity): 
        self.dx, self.dy = new_velocity
    velocity = property(get_velocity, set_velocity)
```

The above is from the source code of a module I am using.

So to get the velocity values individually (dx separately, and dy separately), would this work?

```
self.get_velocity() = lala
lala[1] = dx value and lala[2] = dy value
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because when you want to assign the return value of a function to a variable, you have to have the variable on the left and the function on the right:

```
lala = self.get_velocity()
```

With that one change, it should work. But note that you can do the same thing with less typing like so:

```
dx, dy = self.get_velocity()
```

Answer (score 0):

Erm. You can't do `expression = value`. That doesn't make sense. Try `2 = myvar`

You can do: `dx, dy = self.get_velocity()` or

```
d = self.get_velocity()
dx = d[0]
dy = d[1]
```

In python, when you return a tuple, you can assign multiple variables at the same time.